# How can I make Yahoo! Web mail the default email application?

Tags: yahoo-mail

How can I make Yahoo! Web mail the default email application on a Windows XP machine, hopefully without installing the Yahoo! Toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

It is going to depend on which browser you are running:

**Firefox**: You can change it through Tools->Settings->Applications. Documentation on this can be found [here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Changing%20the%20e-mail%20program%20used%20by%20Firefox).

**Chrome**: There is an extension to make this change occur easily. You can get it [here](http://gmaildefault.codeplex.com/).

**Internet Explorer**: It still looks like you need to get the Yahoo Toolbar to make it happen. You can get it [here](http://toolbar.yahoo.com/ie).

**Safari**: It looks to be a bit trickier. [Here is a link on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/20770/change-default-safari-email-client-to-gmail) on how to make it work with GMail using the GMail notifier, but this might be a Mac Only solution.